# The type "Observable<unknown>" cannot be assigned to the type "Observable<{token:string; }>". tap Error

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, observable

I'm trying to add a token via the .pipe method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private token = null

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(user: User): Observable<{token: string}> {
    return this.http.post<{token: string}>('/api/auth/login', user)
     .pipe(tap(({token}) => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth-token', token)
        this.setToken(token)
     }))
  }

  setToken(token: string) {
    this.token = token
  }
}
```

interfaces.ts

```
export interface User {
  email: string,
  password: string
}
```

Everything works with this code

```
  login(user: User): Observable<{token: string}> {
    return this.http.post<{token: string}>('/api/auth/login', user)
  }
```

When I try to add a token via the .pipe method tap i have a Error

```
The type "Observable<unknown>" cannot be assigned to the type "Observable<{token:string; }>".
The "token" property is missing in the "{}" type and is mandatory in the "{token: string; }" type.ts(2322)
```

Any added method in the .pipe (tap, map and others) as soon as I import them from 'rxjs/operators', this error appears.

Comment: The error does not occur in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2dfi3q?file=src/app/service.ts). Can you reproduce it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very strange that you get this error and i can't reproduce it, but this should fix your problem:

```
login(user: User): Observable<{token: string}> {
  return this.http.post<{token: string}>('/api/auth/login', user)
   .pipe(tap(({token}) => {
     localStorage.setItem('auth-token', token)
     this.setToken(token)
 })) as Observable<{token: string}>
}
```

Comment: Greetings, no the same error is shown. I think there's a bug in the versions. I used the code as a textbook for the study of angulars, and always corrected for errors, and I could not solve this error. This is the complete code that I am studying [link](https://github.com/vladilenm/fullstack)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was in the rxjs versions, I downgraded the version to 6.5.3 and everything worked.